Microsoft Fabric - Change Data Pipeline Owner
Our organization uses MS Fabric to create data pipelines. My predecessor created one pipeline that is central to daily processing of data, however he has left the organization. Everything fell over recently when his access credentials were revoked.
Our investigation shows that the pipeline he created was using his own account and classifies him as the owner. When his account access was revoked (for obvious reasons), that pipeline no longer had access to data and the data ingestion failed.
I am unable to find anything online or in any documentation about how to transfer ownership to another account (preferably a service account).
Any ideas?
Searched online for ideas, but could not find any.

The pipeline takes the role of the user who is running it, so all activities you run have to be allowed by the "new" user. In addition, some connections to data sources have to be configured in the activity. For example, if your connection to data source is to a SQL Server, you have a connection created with some credentials allowing access to SQL Server database. If the connection used by the pipeline is created using his credentials, it won't work, you should update credentials. It's recommeded to use service principal if possible, generic access keys, or at least kind of "super user".
